# How many simulation do I need to cover all connection possibilities of a network (given a number of nodes)?

Tags: networking, simulation, networkx

If I have a network of n nodes, how many simulations (N) do I need to cover all possible combinations of connections between my nodes ? I use a scale-free network (power low sequence with exponent gamma=2).
And second, what N would be if the network was bipartite ?

I got asked by a colleague if the results I get with my network are an artifact because I haven't covered all possibilities. I believe this is not the case, but just to be sure, I'd like to show that my results hold after saturation is attained. A reference (published article) would be valuable !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a full answer we would need to know more about what you've done.

There are a huge number of networks.  It's impossible to even think about covering all possible networks.  Let's assume there are n nodes.  Then there are (n choose 2) = n(n-1)/2 possible edges.  Call this number M.  There are 2^M possible networks.

So it's huge.  Unless n is small, you won't possibly be able to consider all possible networks.

So here's a simple rule of thumb - if whatever you're calculating appears to be converging as you increase the number of networks considered, then it's not a problem.  People do much more rigorous proofs showing things like convergence in probability (as V increases the probability a random graph differs from the limit by more than epsilon goes to zero).

Caveat: if the problem you're trying to solve involves networks with a particular property (say, the average degree is 5), but you're looking at all possible networks where any one network is equally likely, then your result will be different from what is observed for the actual problem of interest.  So you need to be sure that the networks you are sampling have the right properties.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I indeed thought the number would be too huge to attain. I have specified that I use a scale-free network, but what I will do for now is look at the convergence when I increase the number of network simulation, as you suggested. Point is, this is not a simple question !